# Outside CRM income email CRM Dynamics 365

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, crm

Is there a possible way to notice (attribute f.e) if an incoming email is not from the CRM 'universe'? 
For example, an incoming email coming from a Gmail account.

Need to code a plugin and validate if the email is not coming from inside the CRM.

Comment: Dd you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Email pre-create or post-create plugin, verify the sender email address for different domain than yours (ex. agustin@companydomain.com vs marketing_bank@gmail.com) using regular expression and take action.

[Refer: SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16299492)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I 'll let you know in the afternoon

Comment: Arun, It works but it's a pity since I have another doubt. Is it possible to validate at a code level that the plugin isn't shot from the replymail  button inside CRM ?

Comment: @AgustinMoragues if email originated from CRM we can use tracking token to identify from subject, usually it will be like CRM:00123

Comment: If the answer was helpful, pls upvote/accept it to help others find it useful.